# remove heroku repository from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have deleted a Heroku application from the website.

Then when I try to create a new repository using heroku create it tells me that my old application does not exist.

How can I create a new application after deleting the old  one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that [page](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps) provides the answer.

Its content: **Renaming Apps from the CLI**

> You can rename an app at any time with
>   the heroku rename command. For
>   example, to rename an app named
>   “oldname” to “newname”, change into
>   the app’s git checkout and run:

```
$ heroku rename newname
http://newname.heroku.com/ | git@heroku.com:newname.git
Git remote heroku updated
```

Find more details on the provided link.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. That page link had the answer, git remote remove heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You can login into heroku
Click on your app
Click "Settings"
Scroll down to the bottom of the page and click "Delete App"

Hope it help!